# How can I get the children process list in kernel code

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linked-list, task

I want to get to the children task (process) list of a process, here is the code:

```
void myFunc()
{
    struct task_struct* current_task;
    struct task_struct* child_task;
    struct list_head children_list;      

    current_task = current;
    children_list = current_task->children;
    child_task = list_entry(&children_list,struct task_struct,tasks);
    printk("KERN_INFO I am parent: %d, my child is: %d \n",
            current_task->pid,child_task->pid);
}
```

The current pid is right, but the child pid is not correct.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have no knowledge about linux-kernel, but I feel it should be `struct list_head *children_list` and later `children_list = &current_task->children`.

Comment: Thank you but `current_task->children` returns `list_head` and not `list_head*`

Comment: I know it's passed 5 years but what @king_nak is saying is that you **should not** copy struct, but instead use a pointer pointing it. So you put '&' before current_task->children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
child_task = list_entry(&children_list,struct task_struct,children);
```

Note, the last parameter to the list_entry should be `children`

btw: if you are not very familiar with list_entry, following article is a good source: 
http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/